# Customer Address can't remove from view

Tags: magento2.4

I added some customer address thanks to generator https://mage2gen.com/

but now I want to remove it and I can't!!!

Things I did:

- module:disable Vendor_Module
- module:uninstall Vendor_Module
- cache:flush
- setup:di:compile
- setup:upgrade
- setup:static-content:deploy
- remove var/cache, var/view_preprocessed, pub/static/frontend
- remove folder Module
- remove fields from database sales_order_address and quote_address

And nothing works!

What I'm missing?

Thanks